# Name for a uniform local boundedness property of a function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry

I am working with a function $f : \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ having the property that for every $R > 0$, there exists $M > 0$ such that if $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $\vert x - y \vert \le R$, then
$$
  \vert f (x) - f (y)\vert \le M.
$$
By the triangle inequality (and since $\mathbb{R}^N$ is a convex set), it is sufficient for this property to hold for *some* $R > 0$.

These are functions that have a finite “modulus of continuity”, provided you forget about the classical continuity condition on a modulus of continuity. It can be interpreted as a function of bounded maximal oscillation at every scale. Sufficient conditions for this condition are boundedness or uniform continuity.

Equivalently, these functions are characterized by the condition that for every $R > 0$ or for some $R > 0$,
$$
  \sup_{a \in \mathbb{R}^N} \sup_{x, y \in B_R (a)} \vert f (x) - f (y)\vert < \infty.
$$

My question is *whether such functions have a name at some place in the mathematical literature*. Could such function appear naturally in the analysis of mappings between metric spaces?

Answer (score 1):

The term is *coarsely continuous*, also known as *asymptotically continuous* or *large-scale continuous*.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I have had a look to John Roe’s Coarse geometry, and he would use the word bornologous, and in this case, it is equivalent to large-scale continuity.

Comment: Yes, I see that that term is used also. I guess the terminology has not stabilized. The terms I suggested for your property are given in *Recent Progress in General Topology III*, p. 168 (that page isn't available on Google books but you can get the entire book at SciHub).